# smartFix: Extension of TopDown field in Tarmed Product

Tags: ocr

If I extend a TopDown field with an additional subfield from the Tarmed Product, it appears an error message "Subfields cannot be anchored (DDB11780)" if I want to change the Verifier settings of the subfield.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem**
The problem is the TopDown field is connected to one or more anchors. If you add now a new subfield the anchor also be added to the subfield and this produces the failure.

**Solution**
Save the TopDown with the new subfield. Go to the location of the *.sd file. Open it with an editior. Delete the line "ACHOR: {....}" in the subfield (SUBROIS) config and save the file. Reset the DocumentManager. Now you can open the Verifier Options of the subfield without an error.

***Attention*** It matters in which order you mark the anchors (if you have multiple)